# TCSH Makefile - copy file to name and change permissions

Tags: shell, scripting, makefile, tcsh

Im trying to create a makefile for a tcsh script that copies the file to the name proj3 and changes permissions to be executable by everyone. I know how to do makefiles for c++ and c and such but I dont know why we're doing it for shell scripts.

My file name is proj3final

Here is what I have so far:

```
proj3final:
    cp final proj3
    chmod 755 proj3
```

Whenever I run `make proj3` or `make` it prompts `nothing to be done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A makefile rule should **always** create a file with the same name as the target.

If you want make to be able to tell when it needs to run a rule your rule needs prerequisites.

Your rule tells make that it will create the `proj3final` file but it actually creates the `proj3` file. This is going to confuse make.

Additionally, your rule gives that target no prerequisites so whenever the `proj3final` file exists make will assume it is up to date and that no work must be done.

Assuming your input file is named `final` and you want that copied to a file named `proj3final` then the rule you want is

```
proj3final: final
        cp $< $@
        chmod 755 $@
```

Which should do what you want and uses the [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) for the current target (`$@`) and the first prerequisite (`$<`).